# In cakephp what is a autofield

Tags: php, cakephp, lamp

In cake php it explains

"ContainableBehavior can sometimes cause issues with other behaviors or queries that use aggregate functions and/or GROUP BY statements. If you get invalid SQL errors due to mixing of aggregate and non-aggregate fields, try disabling the autoFields setting."

It explains that this maybe the cause to why I can not do a groupby but how do I tweak containable to do what I want.

link below

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable#ContainableBehavior-options-1327

at the bottom of page. But I do not know how to utilize this to use group by . What is autofields ??

Answer (score 1):

With `autofields` enabled, Containable will look for fields it needs and include them in your query. So let's say you have a relation `Person hasMany Email` with `Person` and `Email` being models, and you want to fetch the fields `Person.name` and all related `Email.address` fields. You could do this with a single `find()` call using containable. However, Containable needs to know `Person.id` as well, in order to query on `Email.person_id`. The `autofields` setting will add such "required" fields to the fields array, even if you didn't request them.

This might not solve your problem with the group by though, what are you trying to achieve and what errors do you get?